# How to integrate limits of agreement in uncertainty estimate?

Tags: measurement-error

I would like to estimate a quantity $x$ using a given method (let's call it method $b$) and present it in the form $x \pm u$. Method $b$ is compared to a reference method $a$ by collecting measurements at multiple levels. Consequently, Bland–Altman method is used to construct the limits of agreement between methods $b$ and $a$.

Suppose that limits of agreement are $\pm 0.002$. Suppose that method $a$ has uncertainty $\pm 0.001$. How should I express a quantity estimated by method $b$ in the form $x \pm u$?

The way I'm looking at this is that $x$ is within a confidence interval of $\pm 0.002$ from a quantity that is within a confidence interval of $\pm 0.001$ from the true value. If I sum the extremes of both, I end up with a confidence interval $\pm 0.003$. Finally, I have the estimate of my quantity $x \pm 0.003$.

I appreciate your comments on this line of reasoning.